# how to put tag legend within tag td with zend_form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

My problem is that I want to split addDisplaygroup into 2 parts (legend + input), each part is in a td tag

This is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Member</legend>
            <span>
                <select name="dept" id="dept">
            </span>
            <span>
            <select name="member" id="member">
            </span>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want this :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Member</legend>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>
            <select name="dept" id="dept">
        </span>
        <span>
            <select name="member" id="member">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my addDisplaygroup :

```
$form->addDisplayGroup(array('dept','member'),'register',array(
                        'legend' => 'Member',
                            'decorators' => array(
                                    'FormElements',
                            'Fieldset',
                                array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'),   
                                                            array('tag' => 'td')),
                            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'tr')),
                            ),
                        ));
```

Thanks for any responses.Have a good day !.